# Compiling Opencv with Gstreamer, cmake not finding GStreamer

Tags: opencv, compilation, cmake, gstreamer

I want to build opencv with GStreamer support.

I built the GStreamer from source (version 1.8.1) following this guide:
http://kacianka.at/?p=145
I have 'gstreamer_build' folder at my home directory and it contains 'bin' folder with these:

> gst-device-monitor-1.0 
>   gst-discoverer-1.0  gst-inspect-1.0 
>   gst-launch-1.0  gst-play-1.0 
>   gst-stats-1.0  gst-typefind-1.0 
>   orc-bugreport  orcc

I have this path added to my environment variable PATH.

When I use cmake like:

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D
>   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D
>   OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF
>   ..

I get the following output clearly indicating that gstreamer is not found:

```
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' not found
```

and this:

```
Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.0.1) / libv4l2 (ver 1.0.1)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same problem.

gstreamer-base corresponds to libgstbase-1.0.so (or libgstbase-0.10.so), found in package **libgstreamer1.0-0** (or **libgstreamer0.10-0**, as the case may be). Below, we install the '-dev' package.

The other libraries (libgst-video, libgst-app, libgst-riff, libgst-pbutils) I found in package **libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev** (again, substitute the version you wish to use, either v0.1, or v1.0).

Therefore, the following command should be used to install the missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

Repeat the cmake command, possibly purging the contents of the build directory beforehand.

Comment: Dude you saved me a bunch of time! Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: How can you do this with yum?  I tried it but it doesn't seem that yum has access to whatever repository libgstreamer happens to be in.

Comment: @DanO - Even though this post is 3 years old as of this writing, it works!

Comment: Maybe you know how to also install libavresample to get YES in all rows?

Answer (score 5):

The below worked for me  if you are developing just a Gstreamer applicaiton

```
# GStreamer CMake building
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(GStreamerHello)

set(PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ON)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
if ( NOT (PKGCONFIG_FOUND))
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Please Install PPkgConfig: CMake will Exit")
endif()
pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0>=1.8)
if ( NOT (GST_FOUND))
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Please Install Gstreamer Dev: CMake will Exit")
endif()
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH})

include_directories("${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

link_libraries(${GST_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(gstreamerSrvc  src/hello_gstreamer.cc)
add_dependencies(gstreamerSrvc vsphere_header )
target_link_libraries(gstreamerSrvc ${GST_LIBRARIES}  )
```

Note - If you need a dev docker for GStreamer it is below; and for your question it has the parts of compiling with OpenCV as well;
More details at https://medium.com/techlogs/compiling-opencv-for-cuda-for-yolo-and-other-cnn-libraries-9ce427c00ff8

```
FROM nvidia/cuda
# This is a dev image, needed to compile OpenCV with CUDA
# Install  Gstreamer and OpenCV Pre-requisite libs
RUN  apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
            libgstreamer1.0-0 \
            gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
            gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
            gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
            gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
            gstreamer1.0-libav \
            gstreamer1.0-doc \
            gstreamer1.0-tools \
            libgstreamer1.0-dev \
            libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
RUN  apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y  pkg-config \
 zlib1g-dev  libwebp-dev \
 libtbb2 libtbb-dev  \
 libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev \
 cmake
RUN apt-get install -y \
  autoconf \
  autotools-dev \
  build-essential \
  gcc \
  git
ENV OPENCV_RELEASE_TAG 3.4.5
RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git /var/local/git/opencv
RUN cd /var/local/git/opencv && \
  git checkout tags/${OPENCV_RELEASE_TAG} 
RUN mkdir -p /var/local/git/opencv/build && \
     cd /var/local/git/opencv/build $$ && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_PNG=OFF -D \
    BUILD_TIFF=OFF -D BUILD_TBB=OFF -D BUILD_JPEG=ON \
    -D BUILD_JASPER=OFF -D BUILD_ZLIB=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF -D ENABLE_NEON=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF \
    -D WITH_OPENMP=OFF -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10=OFF \
    -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/ -D WITH_GTK=ON \
    -D WITH_VTK=OFF -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_1394=OFF -D WITH_OPENEXR=OFF \
     -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.0 6.1 7.0 -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX="" -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_TESTS=OFF ..
RUN  cd /var/local/git/opencv/build && \ 
      make install
# Install other tools you need for development
```

Answer (score 4):

On Windows there is no "sudo apt install..." I also had all the paths set right in my PATH environment variable, and still had the same problem. I've got this working after setting following CMake Options:

1. only set "WITH_GSTREAMER" option to True, "WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10" MUST BE FALSE
2. add new entry "GSTREAMER_DIR"=(path to gstreamer)
       for me it was "C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86_64"
   I found this solution [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8836)

My OpenCV version: 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Adding new entry `"GSTREAMER_DIR"=(path to gstreamer)` worked for me (`WITH_GSTREAMER true`).  Did not have a `WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10` in my version.